# C++ Type Traits if_v (automatic type deduction + ensure same type)

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++17, type-traits, variable-templates

Consider the following code

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<bool Test, class T, T val1, T val2>
constexpr T if_v = std::conditional_t<Test, 
                                      std::integral_constant<T, val1>, 
                                      std::integral_constant<T, val2>>::value;

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t value1 = 123;
    constexpr size_t value2 = 456;
    constexpr bool test     = (3 > 2);

    constexpr size_t r0 = if_v<test, size_t, value1, value2>;  // = 123

    return 0;
}
```

Since we know at compile time what the types of `value1` and `value2` are, we should not have to specify it. So we could write

```cpp
template<bool Test, auto val1, auto val2>
constexpr decltype(val1) if_v = std::conditional_t<Test, 
                                                   std::integral_constant<decltype(val1), val1>, 
                                                   std::integral_constant<decltype(val2), val2>>::value;
```

so that we can write a simplified *if* statement `if_v<test, value1, value2>` (without the type). Ideally I'd also like to **ensure that both input values are of the same type**. But I am not sure how to achieve this while using `auto`.

---

Basically, are there better ways to define `if_v` such that we can write `if_v<test, value1, value2>` without having to specify the type, while also somehow `static_assert`ing type equality?

Comment: One solution is to create a backing class for if_v that performs the static assertion in its body. I tried this and it worked. I'll refrain from posting it as an answer as I suspect there are simpler or more elegant solutions (if so, I imagine someone else will post them).

Comment: Can't you just use `? :`? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd also like to ensure that both input values are of the same type. But I am not sure how to achieve this while using auto.

What about using SFINAE ?

I mean

```
template <bool Test, auto v1, auto v2,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(v1), decltype(v2)>, int> = 0>
constexpr auto if_v = std::conditional_t<Test, 
                           std::integral_constant<decltype(v1), v1>, 
                           std::integral_constant<decltype(v2), v2>>::value;
```

or, maybe, simply

```
template <bool Test, auto v1, auto v2,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(v1), decltype(v2)>, int> = 0>
constexpr auto if_v = Test ? v1 : v2;
```

Comment: Oh, very nice :) Constraining the template is much better than indirection here.

Comment: The second simple solution is what i was after, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case, you can solve this by adding another level of indirection. Make your first version of `if_v` that takes the type explicitly into an implementation detail:

```
template<bool Test, class T, T val1, T val2>
constexpr T if_v_impl = std::conditional_t<Test,
                            std::integral_constant<T, val1>, 
                            std::integral_constant<T, val2>>::value;
```

Now you can implement the version with deduced placeholder types by checking whether the deduced types match, and only calling `if_v_impl` in that case:

```
template<bool Test, auto val1, auto val2>
constexpr decltype(val1) if_v = std::is_same_v<decltype(val1), decltype(val2)> 
                                ? if_v_impl<Test, decltype(val1), val1, val2> 
                                : throw;
```

For simplicity, I'm `throw`ing in the false case, since that's not a constant expression, and is sufficient to halt compilation. You can of course produce a custom diagnostic if you really want, for example by delegating to another function that `static_assert`s inside the body.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TMfTGq).